# Overflow Hidden and jQuery conflicting in Chrome & Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit, overflow

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find a solution for this.

I'm using the jQuery Cycle slider in a site. It is used inside a div that currently is set to overflow hidden, while it's images are set to 100% height and 1600px. I am setting the horizontal position through a jQuery call:

This is the CSS:

```
   #large-slider {
   max-height: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   z-index: -1000;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0 auto;
   }

   #large-slider img {
   width: 1600px;
   height : 100%;
   }
```

and this is the jQuery call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// JS call for Cycle Slider
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#large-slider').cycle({
    fx: 'fade'
    });
    // Centering images
    jQuery('#large-slider').css('left', -((1600 - jQuery(window).width()) / 2));
});
    // Centering images on resizing
        jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        jQuery('#large-slider').css('left', -((1600 - jQuery(window).width()) / 2));
    }); 
    </script>
```

NOW, the problem is that in Firefox and IE9 this works perfectly. The images go full width all the time and stay centered no matter what (part of them go outside the screen and we don't see it, but that's perfect). In Chrome, on the other hand, the images fill like 70% of the window width no matter what the size of the window is. In Safari, guess what: the images don't even appear!

This is really strange... I'm using the same script in the same site with another size (like a regular slider without filling the whole width) and it works perfect, so I'm guessing the problem is related to the full width issue, with the overflow hidden, or something. I really don't know.

Any clues??